# Strange Dict behavior with keys of a custom type

Tags: dictionary, julia

I have a recursive function which utilizes a global dict to store values already obtained when traversing the tree.  However, at least some of the values stored in the dict seem to disappear!   This simplified code shows the problem:

```
type id
    level::Int32
    x::Int32
end

Vdict = Dict{id,Float64}()

function getV(w::id)
    if haskey(Vdict,w)
        return Vdict[w]
    end 
    if w.level == 12
        return 1.0
    end
    w.x == -111 && println("dont have: ",w)

    local vv = 0.0
    for j = -15:15
        local wj = id(w.level+1,w.x+j)
        vv += getV(wj)
    end
    Vdict[w] = vv
    w.x == -111 && println("just stored: ",w)
    vv
end

getV(id(0,0))
```

The output has many lines like this:

```
just stored: id(11,-111)
dont have: id(11,-111)
just stored: id(11,-111)
dont have: id(11,-111)
just stored: id(11,-111)
dont have: id(11,-111)
...
```

Do I have a silly error, or is there a bug in Julia's dict?

Comment: Also see related Julia package: [`Memoize.jl`](https://github.com/simonster/Memoize.jl)

Answer (score 6):

By default, custom types come with implementations of equality and hashing **by object identity**.  Since your `id` type is mutable, Julia is conservative and assumes that you care about distinguishing each instance from another (since they could potentially diverge):

```
julia> type Id # There's a strong convention to capitalize type names in Julia
           level::Int32
           x::Int32
       end

julia> x = Id(11, -111)
       y = Id(11, -111)
       x == y
false

julia> x.level = 12; (x,y)
(Id(12,-111),Id(11,-111))
```

Julia doesn't know whether you care about the object's long-term behavior or its  current value.

There are two ways to make this behave as you'd like:

1. Make your custom type immutable.  It looks like you don't need to mutate the contents of `Id`.  The simplest and most straightforward way to solve this is to define it as `immutable Id`.  Now `Id(11, -111)` is completely indistinguishable from any other construction of `Id(11, -111)` since its values can never change.  As a bonus, you may see better performance, too.
2. If you do need to mutate the values, you could alternatively define your own implementations of `==` and `Base.hash` so they only care about the current value:

   ```
   ==(a::Id, b::Id) = a.level == b.level && a.x == b.x
   Base.hash(a::Id, h::Uint) = hash(a.level, hash(a.x, h))
   ```

   As @StefanKarpinski [just pointed out on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/julia-users/q6F7-eVcAkQ/eKXyuyp-4EAJ), this isn't the default for mutable values *"since it makes it easy to stick something in a dict, then mutate it, and 'lose it'."* That is, the object's hash value has changed but the dictionary stored it in a place based upon its old hash value, and now you can no longer access that key/value pair by key lookup.  Even if you create a second object with the same original properties as the first it won't be able to find it since the dictionary checks equality after finding a hash match. The only way to lookup that key is to mutate it back to its original value or explicitly asking the dictionary to `Base.rehash!` its contents.

In this case, I highly recommend option 1.